# Quey Post and comments and User with MySql and knex

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, relationship, knex.js

I have a question about sql query. I use react and node.js. I had been using ORM such as TypeORM, Sequelize, and Prisma.
I switched to Knex which is like a bare SQL just recently.
But I can not get the result I used to get with other ORM. So, I would like some advice.

for example, I have three tables. one is for users and one is for posts and another one is for comments. These tables are connected with a foreign key.
I want to get each post and comment, and the author who created these posts and comments. But If I use JOIN query, It makes a lot of duplicated objects. Any advice would be appreciated.

### Post Table

post_id   |   title  |  content   |

### User Table

user_id  |  user_name  |

### Comment Table

comment_id  |  comment_body  | user_id  | post|_id

### My expectation

```
[
  {
     post_id: 1, title: "title1", 
     content: "content1", 
     user: "user_id1", 
     comments: 
        [{  
           comment_body: "comment 1", 
           user_id: "user_id2 "
         }, {
           comment_body: "comment2"
           user_id: "use_id1 "
         }, {
           comment_body: "comment3"
           user_id: "use_id2 "},
        }] 
  }, 
  ...
]
```

### What I get

```
[{
   post_id: 1,
   content: "content1",
   user: "user_id1", 
   comment_body: "comment1"
 },
{
  post_id: 1,
  content: "content1"
  user: "user_id1", 
  comment_body: "comment2"
 },
 {
  post_id: 1,
  content: "content1"
  user: "user_id1", 
  comment_body: "comment3"
}]
```

Comment: If you want to group the data, you need to do that in JS after the query, you can't do it in MySQL itself.

Comment: ohh... I see. I thought there is a query for that..  I hope I can find an easy npm library to do it.

Comment: Why do you need a library to do it? I gave you a link to a question that shows how. This is not difficult programming.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner programmer. Thank you for your nice advice :D